# Update User: save already filled in details

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have written an update HTML form and a PHP script for my user and it works. Now I want the form to remember what is already filled in.

HTML Form:

What i tried:

```
<td><label>Email:</label></td>
<td><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email()"></td>
```

PHP script:

```
include_once './controler/connect.php';
session_start();

function email()
{
    $username=$_SESSION["user"];

    $sql = "SELECT email FROM `users` WHERE user='$username' ";
    $query = mysqli_query(con(), $sql);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

    return $row["email"];
}
```

Comment: First of all you typed some of your content twice, please edit the question. Second, what error are you seeing? What's not working? What do you want it to do?

Comment: The script that displays the form should perform a query, and fill in the `value` attributes with the current values.

Comment: Why do you have parentheses in the placeholder? The placeholder is just a string that's displayed to the user when the value isn't filled in yet, it's not a function that's called.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, as i said its hard to explain for me in english.
I like that the form remembers what the user allready typed in.
Like the user allready put in the email adress, the email adress stays in the form text field.
The error i got is a blank table.

I tried it first with the placeholder but it was a really stupid idea :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo` the users email in a `value="<?php echo 'whatever' ?>"` inside the `input`. Assuming you have more to this than what you've posted.